# Локальный максимум

Tags: python

Пишу программу которая ищет локальный максимум. Она не компилируется. Не могу понять проблему с синтаксисом..
Хотя по логике все должно работать.

Помогите пожалуйста

```
import random
spisok = []
maxi = 0

for i in range(0,6):
    spisok.append(random.randint(-100,100))

for i in range(1, 6):
    if spisok[i] > spisok[i-1]:
        if spisok[i] > spisok[i+1]:
            maxi = spisok[i]

print(spisok)
print(maxi)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При некоторых входных данных получается ошибка `IndexError: list index out of range`.
Это связно с тем, что в последнем блоке `if` вы используете индекс `i+1`, который выходит за пределы списка.
Если хотите избежать такой проблемы, вы можете организовать такой блок обработки:

```py
for i in range(1, 5): # максимальный индекс на 1 меньше
    if spisok[i] > spisok[i-1]:
        if spisok[i] > spisok[i+1]:
            maxi = spisok[i]
```

В таком случае ни при каких входных данных исключение `IndexError` вызываться не будет.   Правильность программы при этом сохраняется, если учесть, что крайние элементы не могут быть локальными максимумами.

Однако, этот код выдаёт только последний локальный максимум.
Если нужно найти все локальные максимумы, лучше сделать так:

```py
import random
spisok = [random.randint(-100,100) for _ in range(6)]
maxi = []

for i in range(1, 5):
    if spisok[i] > spisok[i-1]:
        if spisok[i] > spisok[i+1]:
            maxi.append(spisok[i])

print(spisok)
print(maxi)
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Обязательно отмечу Ваш ответ =)